# How to get the Summary Statistics and do a K-means Cluster analysis In R for Row Matrices in Loop

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnvDx.png)My primary objective is to analyze a video by splitting it into frames of RGB images and then converting this RGB image into separate color matrices. I did that in MATLAB and imported it into R for analysis. I have 125 frames each with 3 color matrices (R,G and B). I would like to create a loop to get the summary statistics of each color matrix and also do a K-means cluster analysis on each of the matrices.

I did the summary statistics manually for each matrix, which was fine for this video. However, I have several more so I need to find a way to loop it. I tried to do the cluster analysis on red channel of frame 1 using the package `factoextra` and `cluster`.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVwFi.png)

```
df <- Frame1[["redChannel"]]
fviz_nbclust(df, kmeans, method = "wss")
km <- kmeans(df, centers = 3, nstart = 25)
View(km)
kmRed1 <- kmeans(df, centers = 4, nstart = 25)
View(kmRed1)
View(kmRed1)
kmRed1
K-means clustering with 4 clusters of sizes 4, 886, 8, 14
```

One of the clusters has 886 data pints and others just have single digits. I don't understand what it means. I would like to loop this as well for all the other matrices and when I try to plot the cluster using this code:

```
fviz_cluster(km, data = df)
```

I am getting this error message:

```
Error in prcomp.default(data, scale = FALSE, center = FALSE) : 
  cannot rescale a constant/zero column to unit variance
```

I am new To R and would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: You have not provided enough information or a reproducible sample of your data. We have no idea what the structure of `redChannel` is. Is it a matrix? a vector?  a list? . . . .  Given your results I suspect you need to specify more clusters. As it is, you are probably picking up the unique characteristics of frames at the beginning, ending, and scene changes. The rest of the video is getting lumped into a single cluster.

Comment: @dcarlson I have added an image that shows the matrix in frame one, it is a integer matrix of dimension [912x1008] which i converted into a row vector of dimension [1x919296] to get the summary statistics. And as for the cluster analysis I used the fviz_nbclust() function to create a plot of the number of clusters vs. the total within sum of squares from which I got the optimal number as 3.

Comment: I would suggest trying more clusters, 10 or even 20 to start. The "optimal" solution may not be a very useful solution depending on what you are trying to do with the results. The principal components error message is because you have a 886 x 919296. Generally you want more rows than columns for principal components but it is possible to work with more, but probably not that many more.

Comment: @dcarlson I tried with 20 as you suggested and I got the results as (K-means clustering with 20 clusters of sizes 1, 3, 2, 867, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 6, 1, 2, 4, 2, 2)  .I get this error when I try to plot with the following function                                          > fviz_cluster(km, data = df)
Error in prcomp.default(data, scale = FALSE, center = FALSE) : 
  cannot rescale a constant/zero column to unit variance

Comment: I'm not surprised about the error message. See the last sentence of my previous comment. It appears that the frames you are analyzing are very similar to one another. You might look at the groups with less than 10 frames to see what they look like compared to the 867 frames that form a group.