# K-means cluster analysis of row vector in r

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am trying to do a cluster analysis of a row vector

```
str(B1)
 int [1, 1:919296] 136 137 139 202 118 74 63 74 10 5 ...
```

I use the function fviz_nbclust() to determine the number of cluster centers but I am getting the error message

```
fviz_nbclust(c(B1), kmeans, method = "wss")
Error in fviz_nbclust(c(B1), kmeans, method = "wss") : 
  x should be an object of class matrix/data.frame or an object created by the function NbClust() [NbClust package].
>
```

I tried doing the K-means cluster analysis directly and got some results

```
K-means clustering with 10 clusters of sizes 99, 200, 10, 17, 8, 30, 45, 49, 918820, 18

Cluster means:
           [,1]
1  3.403030e+01
2  1.311500e+01
3  1.964000e+02
4  1.370000e+02
5  1.563750e+02
6  1.178667e+02
7  8.884444e+01
8  6.116327e+01
9  1.503015e-03
10 1.782222e+02
```

I would like to know how to interpret the data in a cluster plot

Comment: What does it mean doing cluster analysis "directly"? What cluster plot are you referring to?

Comment: The output of `str(B1)` shows you have a matrix 1x919296. Try transposing it and rerun `fviz_nbclust`.

Comment: This seems to be related to your earlier post: {How to get the Summary Statistics and do a K-means Cluster analysis In R for Row Matrices in Loop}(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74590230/how-to-get-the-summary-statistics-and-do-a-k-means-cluster-analysis-in-r-for-row)

Comment: @RuiBarradas I tried transposing but I am getting the error message "Error: cannot allocate vector of size 3148.3 Gb", I cleared everything and tried again but still getting the same error message.

Comment: See [here](https://uc-r.github.io/kmeans_clustering) how to apply the elbow method with data sets of the size of your `B1`. It runs with me.